# float data[] = new float[j]; why isn't this valid in java ? Cant we have an array in float type?

Tags: java, arrays

when I compile I get this error

```
Solution.java:13: error: possible loss of precision
        float data[] = new float[j];
                                 ^
```

required: int
  found:    float

Got it in the following code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        float sum =0;
        float j = in.nextFloat();
        float data[] = new float[j];
        for(int i=0;i<j;++i)
            {
            float m = in.nextFloat();
             data[i] = m;
        }
        for(int k =0; k<j;++k)
            {
             sum += data[k];
        }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

}

May be I am wrong, a new learner please bear my noobness.

Comment: So if `j` has a value of `4.355745`, how many elements would/should the array have? Why?

Comment: damn got it thank you

Comment: Then how do I add numbers to an array greater than 2^31-1 ?

Comment: Wait. Do you want an array of **size** greater than `2^31-1` or have an array where the element **values** are greater than `2^31-1`?

Comment: element values not the size

Comment: The array initialization (in a variable declaration) syntax is `type[] varName = new type[size];`

Comment: Why cant I use long data[] = new long[j]; ? its an int after all right ?

Comment: No. The type of the array can be anything. The size (and the index for accessing elements) can only be an `int`.

Comment: Oh thanks for helping me figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index of an array must be an int. You can't have an array with 17.54 elements.

If you wish the length of your array to be determined by the value of a `float` variable, you can cast it to int (assuming `j` is not too large) :

```
float data[] = new float[(int)j];
```

Comment: Why cant I use long data[] = new long[j]; ? its an int after all right ?

Comment: @Brewmaster the length of the array must be an int, so again ` long data[] = new long[(int)j];` will work.